# How can I access contacts using Mac CLI app (XCode 14)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, command-line-interface

I'm having some problems accessing contacts inside of mac cli app.
The main issue is that the app is not triggering a dialog requesting access to contacts. Some sources state that [NSContactsUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nscontactsusagedescription) should be added to info.plist. This info.plist is nowhere to be found inside the project in xcode. Then, some sources are stating that there was a xcode update, and now permissions are added on `Targets -> Info` tab, but this tab does not exist on mac cli project.

Here is a code snippet:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Contacts/Contacts.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        CNAuthorizationStatus status = [CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts];

        if (status == CNAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
            NSLog(@"Contact access not determined.");
            CNContactStore *contactStore = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
            
            [contactStore requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                NSLog(@"Got response");
                NSLog(granted ? @"Yes" : @"No");
                CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
            }];
            
        } else if (status == CNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
            NSLog(@"Access granted");
            
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Access to contacts is denied or restricted.");
        }
    }
    CFRunLoopRun();
    return 0;
}
```

Running this outputs: `Contact access not determined.` and app exits with code `0`.

How would one access contacts inside of mac cli app project? Or setup proper permissions so that dialog would trigger?

PS. I have also tried adding info.plist manually, but there was no difference. Maybe I did something wrong? Is info.plist even used in mac cli project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCode 15.1 (15C65) was used, add new plist file with "Info.plist".
turned on Info.plist，add `NSContactsUsageDescription`, and setting build and phaes.
[image]
[image]
Open Mac App with code.
[image]

Comment: `Targets -> Info` is not present when creating cli app project.

Comment: Mac cli app is command line tool?

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/oVOp3L6) is my picture. I can see there is a file named `ViewController` in your project. This seems a bit odd for CLI app. Are you sure you didn't select regular multiplatform project instead of mac->cli?

PS. Yup, CLI is command line tool.

Comment: command line tool Mac app.   1、new plist file with Info.plist. 2、setting  <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.mycorp.myapp</string>
        <key>CFBundleName</key>
        <string>My App</string>
        <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
        <string>record from the camera</string>
    </dict>  .  3、Build Setting - Create Info.plist Section in Binary with YES. 4、Build Setting - Info.plist file set your file path. 5、Build Phases - Copy Files - Destination to Products Directory, and add your info file with `add`

Comment: Thank you, adding this to build phases fixed this issue, and app is now requesting permissions to contacts.